# MPI derived datatypes

Tags: mpi

I want to create derived datatype consists of dynamic arrays, which lengths I don't know, how can I do this? It will be great, if smb post here a simple example. Thanks.

Comment: Can you go into a little more detail? Do your arrays change size during runtime? Do you need to send all the arrays in one message? What's the typemap you want to create?

Comment: I have 3 integers and two arrays of unknown size, it means I'll know it during runtime. And yes, I need to send all this stuff in a single message.

Answer (score 2):

I posted an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651547/mpi-datatype-for-2-d-array/2655363#2655363). In short:

1. You'll need a `HIndexed` datatype.
2. You'll have to use the `MPI_Address()` function to get the proper displacements.
3. You'll have to make sure that the typemap remains valid (i.e. the arrays don't change size or relative position to the other data members), and if it becomes invalid, redefeine and recommit the datatype.